# background-attachment property not working

Tags: html, css, laravel-blade

I am trying to have a page which has scrolling content with fixed background image. It is inside laravel blade template. The problem is it doesn't scroll and is just fixed at one place.

The main layout looks as follows:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <header>
     <style>
      html, body {
         height:100%;
         width:100%;
         overflow:hidden;
      }

      #page-wrap {
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        padding: 20px;
        background: white;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
        min-height: 500px;
        background-attachment: scroll;
      }
     </style>
  </header>

  <body>
    <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/background.jpeg') }}" class="bg">

    @yield('content')

  </body>
</html>
```

The view file is as:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')

<div id="page-wrap">

    Page content which is an html form

</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Some browsers disable `background-attachment` for performance reasons btw, such as Samsung's browser.

Comment: What browser/OS are you on? Safari has some problems with background-attachment see https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attachment though I don't think that would stop the page scrolling.